# C# Linq: Adding another join criteria

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a query:

```
// Query: gets recipients that have not been sent yet....
var query = (from rec in ent.Recipients 
join ch in ent.CampaignHistories on rec.RecipientID equals ch.RecipientID
into chl
from x in chl.DefaultIfEmpty().Where(xx => !xx.RecipientID.HasValue)

select new BRecipient()  
 {
   Email = rec.Email,
   Name = rec.Name,
   RecipientID = rec.RecipientID
 }).Take(remaining);
```

This will basically do a left join in SQL which equates to:

```
Select * FROM            Recipients AS R LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         CampaignHistory AS H ON R.RecipientID = H.RecipientID 
WHERE        (H.RecipientID IS NULL)
```

What I want is:

```
Select * FROM            Recipients AS R LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             CampaignHistory AS H ON R.RecipientID = H.RecipientID
AND H.CampaignID <> 21 
    WHERE        (H.RecipientID IS NULL)
```

How to create the LINQ?

Comment: AND H.CampaignID <> 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it would be:

```
join ch in ent.CampaignHistories.Where(x=>x.CampaignID != 21)
    on rec.RecipientID equals ch.RecipientID
```

But honestly I don't see what you are trying to do. Why would you not simply do:

```
from rec in ent.Recipients
where !ent.CampaignHistories
          .Any(x=>x.RecipientID == rec.RecipientID && x.CampaignID != 21)
select ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = (from rec in ent.Recipients
             join ch in ent.CampaignHistories.Where(xx => !xx.RecipientID.HasValue && xx.CampaignID != 21) on rec.RecipientID equals ch.RecipientID
             into chl
             from x in chl.DefaultIfEmpty()

             select new BRecipient()
             {
                 Email = rec.Email,
                 Name = rec.Name,
                 RecipientID = rec.RecipientID
             }).Take(remaining);
```

Comment: Please put "DefaultIfEmpty()" after the where condition.

Comment: I have updated my code snippet. Please try that and let me know if any concern.